# explaining linq for entry level developer

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database called `_dbObj`.

I have a variable `ID`. I want to `select a value of column"Description" by ID`. The table name is `Disease`.

I just want to know the basic syntax of that simple example.
I was reading on the internet that they can do this through LINQ but when I see the code I got mad.

I see => operator which I did not see before in c# and I see examples like x => x. I see beginner tutorials but I actually do not get the idea. so I want someone to implement my example cuz in my case I think I will understand what are those means.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for code without showing sufficient effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend, that you work through the [entityframeworktutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx). I'm pretty sure that your questions will be answered here.

In short: In Entity you'll have a `DbContext` representing your DB. Example:

```
namespace EF_Code_First_Tutorials
{

    public class SchoolContext: DbContext 
    {
       public SchoolContext(): base()
       {

       }

       public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Standard> Standards { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`DbSet<Student>` represents the `Student` table. To perform queries against the table you can use Linq like:

```
var student = dbCtx.Students.FirstOrDefault( student => studend.Name == "SomeName");
...
```

As stated above I would strongly recomment to work through the entitiy tutorial.

For you problem you could use:

```
var description = _dbObj.Disease.FirstOrDefault(disease => disease.ID == SomeId);
...
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can select a column by finding an item from your context and from that item, selecting the desired column. You can also concatenate these steps to make the code a bit more readable.

```
var description = _dbObj.Disease.First(x => x.ID == yourId).Description;
```

To get values from your context(_dbObj) you need to materialize the Linq to a database query. This is done with `First()` in this case which translates your linq to a sql command tree.